# Passing Data From Activity To Fragment Returns Null

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I am passing data from an activity to fragment, in the fragment the value returned is null. Note that I have setup 2 toasts from the Fragment to test the value of `myValue` and the toast returned is from the else statement where myValue is null.

Activity:

```
            case R.id.forward:

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("message", "From Activity");

            Fragment_02_Contacts  mainFragment = new Fragment_02_Contacts();
            mainFragment.setArguments(bundle);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();

            break;
```

Fragment:

```
String myValue;
.....

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if (myValue != null)
                {
                    myValue = this.getArguments().getString("message");

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message: "+myValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_02_contacts, container, false);
                }
            else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message: "+myValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    // message is null ????
                }
```

EDIT:
I believe that the reason may be linked to:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, mainFragment).commit();
```

Does this destroy my arguments and starts a new fragment?

Answer (score 1):

First assign the value to it, and then check whether it's `null` like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myValue = this.getArguments().getString("message");
        if (myValue != null)
            {
```

The way you've done it before is you checked if the value is `null` before actually ever assigning anything to it (which means it **always was** null), that's why you always ended up in the `else` statement and never in the `if` which held assigning the value.

Comment: If I assign it first the app crashes with: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference, to avoid the app crashing I used if / else, so with your method my app crashes because I am getting a null reference

Comment: This means that the arguments are not set properly. Can you try to pass them in a constructor and then set them there? Also, it's recommended to use Factory design pattern with a static `newInstance` for fragments, look it up.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I finally got it, I am putting the variable in a try / catch clause instead of if / else and the app does not crash anymore because the fragment first starts off as null and caught in a catch and after passing the value from activity the try clause returns data.

```
            try{
            myValue = this.getArguments().getString("message");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message: "+myValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch(NullPointerException e ){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "message: "+myValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

So the idea of if / else was almost correct, it had to be try / catch instead.